# WIN 7 popup with message to replace the disk what we can do about it

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, system-repair-disc

I am very worry today , I got the following message

[image]

please advice if we can use any tools to repair the disk ? or do something else

I cant replaced the disk because some personal issues , so the one choice to to understand if we can repair the disk

please help

Answer (score 2):

Use [HD Tune](https://www.hdtune.com/download.html) to display HDD's SMART attributes. Free version is enough. From there you will be able to determine if the HDD is in danger and needs replacement or there is no significant problem and just a warning.

If you have reallocated and/or bad sectors, you should definitely change the HDD. If it's a simple less relevant warning, there may be nothing wrong with it.

Comment: please help me - how to download the Use HDTune

Comment: I have added a link of the free version download. You just download and install then look at the health tab in it.

Comment: is it also fix something or only monitoring ?

Comment: It is for determining problems. To fix, there are other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is failing, a repair will only delay the inevitable complete failure. You need to back up your files to an external device immediately, and replace the failing drive.

Answer (score 0):

Windows detected that the disk has started to fail. If you don't backup your files they could be permanently lost. All hard drives will fail eventually, there's practically nothing you can do. Start considering replacements now.

Comment: any way how to repair the disk , any tool in win that will do that?

Comment: You can run a `chkdsk /r` in command prompt. That will "fix" any "corrupted" sectors on the disk. Make sure to read the output at the end as it will tell you if any corrupted data was found. However it's similar to putting a band-aid on a gaping wound, and WILL NOT fix any underlying hardware problems. Hard drive replacement is inevitable.